# Email Function - Webforms drupal 7

Tags: webforms, drupal-7, smtp, email, smtp-auth

Here I have two queries:

1. SMTP authentication in MS Outlook mail
2. Used modules are SMTP authentication and webforms for drupal 7

Initially I used the gmail domain for SMTP authentication mails triggered to my recipients. Here my requirement is Microsoft outlook domain for SMTP authentication. My recipients are unable to receive mail. Please guide me.

1. SMTP AUTHENTICATION

   Here I used the steps:

   - Turn this module on or off --> on
   - Turn on delivery of emails --> on
   - SMTP SERVER SETTINGS:

     > SMTP server  --> smtp.office365.com
     >   SMTP Port  --> 587
     >   encrypted protocol --> TLS
     >   SMTP AUTHENTICATION (used microsoft outlook mail)
     >   Username: ---> retail@companyname.com
     >   Password: ----> xxxxxxxxxxx
2. How can I add CC and BCC in mail by using webforms in drupal 7?

Answer (score 0):

You can send emails to multiple addresses, the email can be send to each address separately (if you don't want all recipients to see each other) or you can send one email to multiple addresses. Configuration is located on your webform: node/yourNID/webform/emails

However if you really wish CC there's a module for that: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_cc

Or you can create your own function:

mytheme_webform_mail_headers($variables) {

```
    $headers = array(
    'X-Mailer' => 'Drupal Webform (PHP/' . phpversion() . ')',
    );

    $headers['cc'] = 'email@example.com';

    return $headers;
}
```